# How to write a view filter to show all pages created by me and have either “Pending” or “Approved” statuses

Tags: 2013, document-library, list-view, filter, view

I want to achieve this , to display all pages that are assigned to me and have either (Pending or approved) statuses.
But when I define the following, 
[image]

It will show all the pages that are rejected even if they are not created by me !!
Can anyone advice, If I can extend the “is equal to” to have an array of strings ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to do it the other way round.

Make it:

Approval Status
is equal to
rejected

**OR**

Approval Status
is equal to
pending

**AND**

Created by
is equal to
[Me]

which gives you (a OR b) and c.

Comment: what is the rule in this situation ? should i always write the ORs then the Ands ?

Comment: The filters are used in the order you set them. Given your example, the first filter gets the items Created By you, then filter the returned results (AND) to get only the "Pending" items, then combine the results of first two filters (OR) with the items that were "Rejected". Thus you get the items that are pending and created by you, but also all items that were rejected, even though they were not created by you.